# Why is the total work done on an object its change in kinetic energy, but not change in total energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

We have just started learning so explain simply. We don't know about conservative or non conservative forces. We are just learning basics.

Comment: More on the [work-energy theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Benergy%5D+%5Bwork%5D+%5Bnewtonian-mechanics%5D+%22work-energy%22+is%3Aq).

Comment: Well, because that is the _definition_ of kinetic energy.

Comment: Who says it's *not* a possible change in total energy using work? Consider a box with wheels initially at rest on some table. You come along and push the box, making it move along the table. You just increased its kinetic energy and its total energy. You're making an "either-or" statement about something which can be "both-and"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior effort](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/25301)

Comment: The work/kinetic-energy theorem implicitly assumes no change in potential energy.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are doing basics, I will keep with the simple assumptions of a constant *net* (total) force $F$ in one dimension acting on an object of mass $m$. We will also assume your object is a rigid body so that we can't store energy in the deformation of the object.

By Newton's second law, we know the acceleration is constant and given by $$a=\frac Fm$$ Also, since the acceleration is constant we can use the following kinematic equation $$v_f^2=v_i^2+2a\Delta x$$ where $v_i$ and $v_f$ are the initial and final velocities respectively corresponding to the beginning and end some time interval, and $\Delta x$ is the distance traveled in that time interval.

Therefore, 
$$v_f^2=v_i^2+2\frac Fm\Delta x$$
or, using some algebra
$$F\Delta x=\frac12mv_f^2-\frac12mv_i^2$$

If we define $F\Delta x$ to be the total work done on the object, and $\frac12mv^2$ to be the kinetic energy, we see that the total work done on the object results in a change in kinetic energy. No other types of energy need to be addressed to apply this equation.$^*$

> they say work done causes transfer of energy so why cant that energy be potential energy.

$W_{total}=\Delta K$ does not mean that we can't do work to change the potential energy of the object. I know you say you haven't gotten to this yet, but we have to talk about conservative forces here. A conservative force is, for our purposes, a force that we can associate a potential energy with. Gravity is one such example. Gravity turns out to be conservative, so we can have gravitational potential energy.

A nice property of conservative forces is that the work they do on an object is equal to the negative change in potential energy.
$$W_{cons}=-\Delta U$$
so what this means is that we can either look at the work done by conservative forces, or we can instead just consider the change in potential energy.

As an example, let's say I am lifting a book upwards at a constant speed (which also means constant kinetic energy). Since the book's speed is constant, we have the for total work done (by both me and gravity, the only forces acting on the book) $$W_{total}=\Delta K=0$$

If we instead decide to consider potential energy, what do we have? Well then we can say
$$W_{total}=W_{me}+W_{grav}=W_{me}-\Delta U=0$$
Or
$$W_{me}=\Delta U$$
And so we usually say in this scenario that "the work I do is converted into the potential energy of the book."

So, *total* work just changes the kinetic energy. This does not mean that potential energy doesn't change. It's just that in the equation $W_{total}=\Delta K$ the change in potential energy is already included in the total work as work done by the conservative force.

---

**An aside for the commenters** I am not saying that forces can't do things like change potential energy. It is just true that the *total* work done on an object is equal to its change in kinetic energy. This is not saying that the only thing work can do is change kinetic energy.

To bring it closer to home, in general we can split the total work done into the work done by conservative and non-conservative forces.
$$W_{total}=W_c+W_{nc}=\Delta K$$
But, as discussed above, $W_c=-\Delta U$. Therefore
$$W_{nc}-\Delta U=\Delta K$$
or
$$W_{nc}=\Delta U+\Delta K=\Delta E$$

This is typically what you see as "energy conservation", where only the non-conservative forces can change the total mechanical energy.

Of course you could choose to only consider the potential energy of some of the conservative forces and not all of them. Then you could interpret the equation as 
$$W_{ext}=\Delta U'+\Delta K=\Delta E$$

where the primed potential energy is just to differentiate from the previous equation that involved all conservative forces rather than just some of them. $W_{ext}$ can be viewed as the work done by "external forces", which in this case are all non-conservative forces as well as any conservative forces whose work we are not taking into account by using potential energy.

---

$^*$For the more advanced reader, we can do similar arguments with non-constant forces and in more dimensions, but we end up at a similar relation
$$W_{total}=\int\mathbf F\cdot\text d\mathbf x=\Delta K$$
where this is a line integral performed over the path the particle moves along.

Comment: they say work done causes transfer of energy so why cant that energy be potential energy.Some people also say workdone is equal to change in mechanical energy of the object .This confuses me why only kinetic energy. What is the generalized principle

Comment: @SangeetaGulati, That is what he has proven.In the last equation we get FΔx(work done) = Δmv^2 (change in kinetic energy).

Comment: @VaishakhSreekanthMenon So this is genralized?

Comment: @SangeetaGulati I have added more to address your inquiry.

Comment: Also why does this answer deserve a downvote?

Comment: Work can also be done by increasing an object's potential, thermal or even internal strain energy. And many other ways, such as chemical work. Like the work done when our body burns food to create energy.

Comment: @kamran I never said work can't do any of those things

Comment: @AaronStevens I cant even vote probably so i have not downvoted

Comment: @SangeetaGulati That's ok. Do things make more sense now? The equation $W_{total}=\Delta K$ isn't saying that the only thing the work done by a force can do is change kinetic energy

Comment: if we consider conceptually if there is a system on which work is done and both kinetic and potential energy increased so if total work done(energy transfered) is equal to change in kinetic energy how does the potential energy of the system increased as energy transfered only increased its kinetic energy@AaronStevens

Comment: @SangeetaGulati The total work done already includes changes in potential energy. Changes in potential energy is just a fancy term meaning "(negative) work done by conservative forces"

Comment: @AaronStevens Sorry Aaron, I posted my answer before seeing your latest edit which got it covered. I up voted it.

Comment: @BobD oh no worries at all. I'm just glad to have someone here to support what I have been saying. Comments and discussion on everything else here has been fighting back against me and misinterpreting what I am saying haha

Comment: @AaronStevens If I lift an object at rest off the ground and bring it to rest at a height $h$ above the ground I believe I and gravity both do work. What is the resulting change in kinetic energy and the net work done?

Comment: @BobD The net work is $0$ and so is the change in kinetic energy.

Comment: @AaronStevens If the net work is $0$ how did the object obtain potential energy and have no change in kinetic energy?

Comment: @BobD Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91165/discussion-between-aaron-stevens-and-bob-d).

Comment: @AaronStevens Agree

Answer (score 2):

The principle you are describing is referred to as the work-energy principle, or work-energy theorem.

@Aaron Stevens has shown you how the principle can be derived from Newton’s second law.  I would like to build on that.

I am going to assume that when you say “total energy” you mean kinetic and potential energy and that you are thinking that potential energy is somehow missing from the work-energy principle because it only refers to kinetic energy. It’s important to understand that this principle involves any kind of force and work, including the work done by gravity, and as such it does not preclude the possibility that the object has gained or lost potential energy.

Let’s say we have object with mass $m$ at rest at a height $h$ above the surface of the earth and that the height is not so great so that the force of gravity is constant.  As such, the object possesses gravitational potential energy of $mgh$. The object is released and allowed to fall.

While falling the gravitational field exerts a constant downward force of $mg$. Since the direction of the force is the same as the displacement of the object (downward) gravity does positive work $w$ on the object

$$w=mgh$$

Ignoring air friction, according to the work energy theorem the work done on the object equals its change, in this case increase, in kinetic energy, or

$$mgh=\frac {mv^2}{2}$$

Where $v$ is the velocity just prior to impact with the ground.

Note that the work-energy principle satisfies the law of conservation of energy. The object has gained kinetic energy but lost an equal amount of potential energy. The total energy of the object (potential plus kinetic) is conserved.

The change in potential energy of the object has been accounted for in the application of the principle by knowing the nature of the force that is doing the work.  There is no need to explicitly refer to potential energy in the principle itself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is exactly right, and this is the point I was also trying to make that when we talk about the *total* work we have already included the change in potential energy.

Comment: Why was this  down voted

Comment: Some people like to downvote every answer on a question they think isn't a good question. It doesn't deter me though because I still get more points than what they take away, so it's not a useful tactic

Comment: @AaronStevens Thanks for explaining that. It won't deter me either. In any case, I don't mind a down vote if there is a reason I can learn from. I understand the need for anonymity, but feel there should be a mechanism for finding out the rationale for a down vote without needing to know the source.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of responses to your question and that's probably because it was a good one (and has been asked many times before in different ways). In my opinion, all the analysis and examples that others and I have given can be summed up in terms of the following statement made by @Aaron Stevens (words in parenthesis added by me):

***“This (the work-energy theorem) is not saying that the only thing work can do is change kinetic energy”***

What the work-energy theorem does say is a change in kinetic energy of an object can only occur when net work is done on the object. Alternatively, the net work done an object will only result in a change in kinetic energy of the object.

These statements can be illustrated in the following scenarios involving gravity. See the Figure below. The only things you are expected to know to follow the explanation are the following:

1. In order for net work to be done on an object it must be subjected to a net force that causes displacement of the object.
2. If the force on an object is in the same direction as the displacement of the object, the work done is positive. This means energy has been transferred to the object from the source.
3. If the force on an object is in the opposite direction as the displacement, the work done is negative. This means that energy has been transferred from the object to the source.
4. If the net force on an object is zero, then the velocity of the object is either zero or constant.
5. The gravitational potential energy of an object with respect to the surface of the earth is a function only of its height above the surface. One must, therefore, consider the object and the earth together as a system.

In the figure below an object of mass $m$ is initially at rest on the surface of the earth. The scenarios are summarized as follows:

**Scenario 1:** The mass is lifted by an external force (me) to rest at a height $h_{f}$ above the surface of the earth by my applying an average upward force to the object equal to the downward gravitational force on the object, so that the net work done on the object is zero. The work done in lifting the mass is stored as gravitational potential energy. I (i.e. my muscles) supplied this energy.

**Scenario 2:** The mass from scenario 1 is allowed to fall. Gravity does net positive work giving the mass kinetic energy upon contacting the ground, per the work energy theorem, equal to its initial gravitational potential energy.

**Scenario 3:** The mass is lifted with the application of an upward force twice the downward force of gravity. The net upward force does positive work on the mass giving it kinetic energy per the work energy theorem. By the time the mass reaches $h_{f}$ it will have both kinetic and potential energy.

The following are the details of the three scenarios.

**SCENARIO 1:**

In order to start the process I need to initially apply an upward force on the object slightly greater than the downward force of gravity to give perform work on the object giving it positive kinetic energy per the work-energy theorem.

I quickly reduce my upward force so as to equal the downward gravity force, so that the mass continues upward at constant velocity while no net work is done. During this time I do positive work while gravity does an equal amount of negative work.  To say that gravity is doing negative work on the mass is equivalent to saying the mass does positive work on gravity. So during this time I am transferring energy to the mass and the mass, in turn, is transferring the same amount of energy to the gravitational field where it is being stored as gravitational potential energy.

Before reaching the top I reduce my upward force on the object to slightly less than the downward force of gravity so that the object has zero velocity when it reaches $h_{f}$. This results in negative work done by gravity and a negative change in kinetic energy, per the work energy theorem, equal to the positive kinetic energy  at the beginning.

Overall, my average upward force equals the downward force of gravity and no net work is done and the total change in kinetic energy is zero. The net result is the total change in energy is the increase in gravitational potential energy. This increase in gravitational potential energy is now available to do work in the scenario 2.

**SCENARIO 2:**

I release the mass at height $h_{f}$ allowing it to freely fall. The only force on the mass is now the downward force of gravity, which is in the same direction as the displacement of the mass. Consequently, gravity is doing net positive work on the mass at the expense of the stored gravitational potential energy.  Per the work-energy theorem this results in an increase in kinetic energy. By the time the mass reaches the bottom, all of the gravitational potential energy is converted to kinetic energy.

**SCENARIO 3:**

In this scenario I exert a constant upward force of twice the downward gravitational force for the entire height $h_{f}$. There is therefore a net upward force of $mg$ and net positive work done is done equal  $mgh_{f}$ by the time it reaches $h_{f}$. That net positive work equals the increase in kinetic energy that the mass has as it passes by $h_{f}$. But the mass also has an increase in potential energy such that the total change in energy when it reaches $h_{f}$ is the sum of its change in kinetic and potential energy, as shown in the figure.

CONCLUSION:  *These three scenarios illustrate that the change in kinetic energy of an object is solely due to net work being done on the object, whereas the change in gravitational potential energy was due to the simultaneous transfer of energy from a source of energy (me) to the object and from the object to the gravitational field, where it is stored as gravitational potential energy for the object-earth system.*

Hope this helps.
[image]

Comment: I think you have covered some good scenarios here. +1. Too bad it seems like the OP's account has been deleted or something?

Comment: why was this down voted

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that the work-energy theorem should really only be applied to a particle (point like object) and treating a particle as the system under consideration means that the particle cannot have potential energy.

So an external force acting on a particle (the system) can do work on the particle and only change the kinetic energy of the particle.

You may say what about a mass $m$ falling a distance $h$ in gravitational field of strength $g$ does the mass not lose potential energy $mgh$?
The answer is -  no, it is the mass **and** Earth system which loses the gravitational potential energy ie you are no longer dealing with just one particle.
If you are considering the mass alone as the system then the external force on the mass is $mg$ and after falling a distance $h$ the work done by that external force is $mg \times h$ and this is equal to the change in kinetic energy of the mass.

The problem is that in this case the work done by the external force on the mass alone system $mgh$ looks suspiciously like the change in the gravitational potential energy of the mass **and** Earth system when the mass is a height $h$ above the zero of potential energy.
Note that the system here is not just the mass but the Earth as well. 
This confusion can arise because of the fact that the mass of the Earth is so much greater than the mass of the object which is falling.
The Earth is assumed not to move and the increase in the kinetic energy of the falling object is taken to be equal to the loss in the gravitational potential energy of the object and Earth system.

Gain in kinetic energy of the falling object (and the Earth $=0$) = loss in gravitational potential energy of the object and Earth system.

In simple terms if you want to use the work-energy theorem define a point like object as the system under consideration, identify the external forces acting on that system and avoid any reference to potential energy.

Comment: We certainly can say an object experiences a force due to an interaction between the object and another object. Why can't we say that this object also has potential energy due to this interaction as well? Why can't we say the potential energy of the object is given by $U-U_0=-\int \mathbf F\cdot \text d\mathbf x$ where we integrate over some path starting at the reference point with $\mathbf F$ being the conservative force? In other words I don't understand why we can't say the object has potential energy just because it arises from an interaction.

Comment: @AaronStevens Although I understand what you have written I think that it is not the way to introduce potential energy. Two masses $A$ & $B$ are $x$ apart. Keeping mass $A$ fixed, mass $B$ is moved by external force to a separation $y (>x)$ with the external force doing work.  Going back to the original configuration mass $B$ is fixed and mass $A$ is moved so the separation is again $y$. The external force has done work & the work done is equal to that when $B$ moved. In both cases the potential energy increased but which mass has the potential energy?

Comment: I don't think "which mass has the potential energy" is the right question to ask. I am not saying all of the energy is stored in only one of the masses. I am saying that just how we say each object has a force of, for example, $3\rm N$ acting on it without having any issues, I don't see why we can't (carefully) say each object has a potential energy associated with it.

Comment: The only issue would be if you wanted to determine the total potential energy of the system you would not add these energies together since you would then be "double counting". But a similar idea arises with the forces. You never add together the interaction forces to determine the net force acting on the system. Similarly, you would have a separate understanding that the total energy comes from the interaction and not what we say is the energy of each mass individually.

Comment: I’m not saying this is appropriate in all situations, but I don’t see why in situations where we really are just focused on one body we can’t just say it has a potential energy associated with it.

Comment: A thought-provoking answer. I've always regarded talking about the increase in gravitational energy of a lifted-up body as a sloppy attribution of energy that really belongs to the Earth-body system, but haven't thought that such sloppy talk did much harm. I'm still pondering...

Answer (score -1):

Total work done on object is equal to the change of the object  kinetic energy $E_\mathrm{k}$, if there is no change of the object internal energy. (but see the appendix about potential energy).

If no rotation is involved - typicaly for point-like objects - we can consider just translational kinetic energy:

$W=\Delta\ K_E = 0.5 . m.(v_2^2-v_1^2)$

If acting forces have tangential components with respect to object centre of mass, we have to consider changes of rotational energy as well.

$W=\Delta\ K_E = 0.5 . m.(v_2^2-v_1^2) + I.(\omega_2^2-\omega_1^2) $

$m$ is object mass 
$I$ is object moment of inertia
$v_2, v_1$ is final and initial speed
$\omega_2, \omega_1$ id final and initial angular speed

**The work done by the resultant force, mentioned elsewhere, is tricky:**

- The resultant force can be zero, but still, the partial forces causing torque can affect rotational energy.
- OTOH, saying the resultant force affects just translational energy is not true, as it can cause exchange of angular momentum.

**But most real life cases involve changes of the object internal energy.**

The simple examples the total work is not equal to the kinetic energy change
are:

- An inelastic collision

  - a collision of 2 clay balls
  - a bullet caught in a test block
- Object changes due tidal forces in gravity gradient without direct contact.

  - Jupiter-Io interaction
  - [Roche limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit).
- A reversible object deformations

  - a spring or object priming
  - oscillations

Very most of real life object interactions are these cases.

---

Note the change of the potential energy in external conservative field (PE) is de facto work done by the object against the field and stored in the field. This work is subtracted from the total work done on the object.

Important thing is also that we have to consider all three fundamental conservation laws:

- The energy conservation
- The momentum conservation
- The angular momentum conservation

It may be less obvious, but nonzero angular momentum is not related only to circular motion, but also to linear motion along a line missing the coordinate system origin.

But it is not essential to answer the OP principal question.

Comment: The OP asks about *total work*, not work done by single forces, potential energy, etc.

Comment: But it applies to total work as well.

Comment: The total work gives you the change in kinetic energy. It doesn't depend on the scenario.

Comment: In sense, sometimes it is equal to kinetic energy change, sometimes to total energy change, and sometimes to neither of them,

Comment: ...following delta U = delta A + delta Q, As change if total energy is sum of applied work and provided thermal energy.

Comment: I'll agree that if the only energy is kinetic then the total work done changes the total energy. But it is always the case that the total work done on an object is equal to its change in kinetic energy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91142/discussion-between-aaron-stevens-and-poutnik).

Answer (score -1):

Rewritten, simplified and shortened...

The resultant force on a body is what gives the body an acceleration. If the body moves in the same direction as the resultant force, the acceleration takes the form of an increase in speed. Therefore the kinetic energy increases. Indeed, it's easy to show that, with the usual nomenclature,

$$\text{Work done by resultant force} = \tfrac12 m v^2-\tfrac12 m u^2.$$

To tackle your query about potential energy, let's imagine a simple set-up. Attach a rope to a box of mass *m* (directly above the box's centre of mass) and pull the rope so that it exerts a constant upward force $F_{rope}$ (>$mg$) on the box, lifting the box through a height $h.$

$$\text{Resultant force on box} = F_{rope}-mg$$

Multiplying through by $h,$

$$(\text{Resultant force on box})h = F_{rope}h-mgh$$

That is
$$\text{Gain in KE of box}=\text{Work done by rope}-\text{Gain in grav'l PE of box}.$$

Hope you see how everything fits into place.

Answer (score -2):

The work done on an object can be basically defined as the amount of energy expended to translate or displace a body through a distance in space. So whatever you do, as long as you use energy and change the position (displace) of the body through space, you've done work, and the energy embodied by that mass due to your work is equal to the energy expended to do the work, provided no loss of energy was experienced. Work has a formula: $$W=F\Delta d$$

The Newton second law of motion also says a body of mass $m$ accelerates with magnitude $a$ if a force $F$ is acting on it: $$F=ma$$
Acceleration is defined to be the change in velocity $v$ over time $t$. When a body changes velocity, it gains kinetic energy.

> A force that does work against another constantly and continuously acting force and stores the energy in the process increases potential energy, and a force that doesn't work against and otherwise transforms the energy into more and more motion increases kinetic energy.

A body's total ""**Mechanical**"" energy is the sum of its kinetic and potential energy at a particular moment and point in space. A body accelerating, decelerating, or uniformly displacing upward against gravity for example has both kinetic and potential energy at every point until its velocity turns zero at the apogee where potential energy is **maximum**. A body starting from ground level (at height zero) at velocity $v$ has a kinetic energy $\frac 12 mv^2$ and potential energy $mg(0)$, hence its total mechanical energy is its kinetic energy.

Bottom line, a body's total mechanical energy can be all in kinetic or all in potential or somewhere in-between where there's both potential and kinetic at some point.

Comment: *A force that does work against another constantly and continuously acting force creates potential energy, a force that doesn't work against creates kinetic energy.* This doesn't make sense. If I push a box across a surface with fiction then my force resists friction but the potential energy isn't changing.

Comment: I do believe in the context of the subject being dealt with, anyone should understand what I mean by that. But if the wording do bothers you, I'll gladly amend it. Just be kind enough to revoke that down-vote.

Comment: It's not the wording that bothers me, it's the content. That isn't a correct statement, and I have provided a counter-example showing why it is not true.

Comment: Well maybe edit I just did make a difference. And the down-vote please!!

Comment: "When a body changes velocity, it gains kinetic energy. "  That's just wrong. Consider uniform circular motion.